# How can I get the length of the longest string in a column (Excel)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I am writing out to a file.  I am currently using the following method to reproduce the contents of each cell:

```
cell_contents = Right(Space(10) & Trim(Cells(iRow, iColumn)), 10)
```

However, if the contents of the cell are longer than 10 characters long (or however long I choose to specify), then I loose parts of the data.  Is there a way to quickly and easily get the length of the longest string in a range of cells?

I have seen people suggest using the following loop, but I was hoping that I might be able to do it without having to loop over all the cells:

```
For Each c In SourceRange.Cells
   if len(c) > b then b = len(c)
Next c
```

Comment: Either use the =Len() formula in a new column, sort the cells by length and get the first cell or loop through them and compare lengths.

Comment: @Ripster I really need to avoid entering additional content to the sheet and keep everything inside VBA.

Answer (score 9):

Record these steps as a macro in the cell you want to calculate the max length.

1) enter this formula

```
=MAX(LEN(A1:A4), 1) -- Edit for your range.
```

2) `press control-shift enter` (FormulaArray)

3) now stop recording macro

4)  view the VBA.  copy what you need to your VBA.

Should give you something like this:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=MAX(LEN(R[-10]C[1]:R[-1]C[1]))"
```

Comment: I should have thought to use the macro recorder to record entering an array formula.  That should work nicely!  Thanks!

Comment: When needing VBA for something you know you can do via formula or series of steps, I always use the macro recorder.  I generally learn more about existing VBA functions this way; and it saves me the research time.

Comment: I knew this and have done this before as well. I don't know why I didn't think of it in this case. Do you know if it is possible to calculate the result from the array formula inside VBA instead of having to enter it into a cell on the worksheet? The documentation for [`Application.Evaluate`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080550418.aspx) explains how to evaluate Excel expressions in VBA, but this does not work for array formulas.

Comment: Ancient question: but I do not.

Answer (score 7):

Press `Alt-F11`, insert new module, paste code bellow.

```
Public Function maxRangeLength(data As Range) As Integer
    Dim ret As Integer

    ret = 0

    For Each cell In data
        ret = Application.Max(ret, Len(cell))
    Next cell

    maxRangeLength = ret
End Function
```

Usage:

```
=maxRangeLength(A8:D11)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could just use ... {=MAX(LEN(A2:A200))}

In the top cell put =MAX(LEN(A2:A200)) .. and then press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER to get the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the data is in column A and there is a heading row for your spreadsheet.

1. Create a new column next to it and enter in the formula: =LEN(A2)
2. Autofill down that formula.
3. Turn on filtering for that column and the click the drop-down box on the column heading cell.
4. Scroll down to the bottom of the list where the largest summarized value is.
   That will be the largest value in the column.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I was looking for a solution with VBA, not formulas on the sheet.