# Excel validation for multiple values paste

Tags: excel

I am trying to restrict users to enter a 12 digit value for an ID.
I am using following macro for that;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Column <> 1 Then GoTo Exit_Sub
    If Len(Target.Value) <> 12 Then
        MsgBox " Plese enter exactly 12 characters!!"
        Application.Undo
    End If
Exit_Sub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This works SUCCESSFULLY for one by one value. If I copy and try to paste "1234" it doesn't work. But if I copy paste in a bulk i.e. for multiple rows. Then it all breaks and validation doesn't work.
Kindly suggest.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Why not use Data Validation?

Comment: Second data validation but to your macro if you have multiple cells are selected then your target is a range of multiple cells so you can't use target.value directly you would need to use something like `for each c in target` and check on a cell by cell basis. Or use an array formula to check the max and min length of string [see example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678242/how-can-i-get-the-length-of-the-longest-string-in-a-column-excel)

Answer (score 0):

To handle multiple cells you need a *loop:*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then GoTo Exit_Sub
        For Each r In Target
            If Len(r.Value) <> 12 Then
                MsgBox " Plese enter exactly 12 characters!!"
                r.Value = ""
            End If
        Next r
Exit_Sub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```